# Dockerized Django app not allowing connections

Tags: python, django, docker

I have a Django project that im trying to dockerize. When I run the the docker image i get no errors and the django app says it waiting for connections. Navigating to localhost, 127.0.0.1, or my VMs ip return no connection and the Django terminal reports no incoming connections.

this is how i build and run my docker image

```
docker build -t 0rion447/osas:osas_latest
docker run -it -p 80:8000 0rion447/osas:osas_latest
```

here is my dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8.5
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip3 install --user -r requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install psycopg2-binary
RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade Pillow
COPY . app
COPY run_server.sh ./
RUN chmod +x run_server.sh
EXPOSE 8000

ENTRYPOINT ["./run_server.sh"]
```

and my run_server.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
python app/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

In my settings.py i have

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS['*']
```

Let me know if you need any other information.

Answer (score 0):

it was running on port 80 not 8000 like the terminal reported

Answer (score -1):

Is your app actually running?  When you run

```
docker run -it -p 80:8000 0rion447/osas:osas_latest
```

the `-it` (interactive terminal) is essentially overriding your `ENTRYPOINT`, so unless once you get the prompt inside the container you run `./run_server.sh`, I don't think your django app is ever starting.

Try running just

```
docker run -p 80:8000 0rion447/osas:osas_latest
```

or using a docker-compose file to start your app

Comment: ya its acutally running, -it displays the django app info so i can monitor the django server.

Comment: The `-it` options only change whether the container's process has something available on its stdin; they don't change what that process is at all.